# E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout (Android)

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, picasso, android-recyclerview

I have attached my adapter to my main activity's onCreate, after loading the user data to a model class named (Users.java) and then passing this ArrayList to the adapter.I am using Firestore.
It was working earlier but then after a few tests it stopped working. App crashes as soon as main activity is loaded. Please help. Thanks in advance.

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // To make App Bar from Action Bar (AppComp)
    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    // Check if user is signed in (non null) and update UI accordingly.
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if (currentUser == null) {
        Intent authIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignUpActivity.class);
        startActivity(authIntent);
        finish();
    } else {

        mUsers = new ArrayList<>();
        db.collection("users")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                                Users users = document.toObject(Users.class);
                                mUsers.add(users);
                            }
                            mAdapter = new UsersAdapter(MainActivity.this, mUsers);
                            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                            ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar9);
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

UsersAdapter.java

```
public class UsersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UsersAdapter.UsersViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<Users> mUsers;

public UsersAdapter(Context context, List<Users> users) {
    mContext = context;
    mUsers = users;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public UsersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.users_card, parent, false);
    return new UsersViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UsersViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Users currentUser = mUsers.get(position);
    holder.textViewName.setText(currentUser.getUserName());
    Picasso.get()
            .load(currentUser.getUserImageUrl())
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .into(holder.imageViewPhoto);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mUsers.size();
}

public class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public ImageView imageViewPhoto;
    public TextView textViewName;

    public UsersViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        imageViewPhoto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_image);
        textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_name);

    }
}
```

}

Logcat

```
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.sandeeppradhan.sailors, PID: 3286
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must not be empty.
    at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.load(Picasso.java:332)
    at com.example.sandeeppradhan.sailors.UsersAdapter.onBindViewHolder(UsersAdapter.java:39)
    at com.example.sandeeppradhan.sailors.UsersAdapter.onBindViewHolder(UsersAdapter.java:17)
```

Comment: `RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout` is just a warning, saying you don't have an adapter setup yet. That's probably before your data is fetched from your server. What is the actual crash? Can you post your stacktrace?

Comment: @Advice-Dog my Logcat posted. Please check. Thanks

Comment: @Advice-Dog Yes that was just a warning, I got the problem, the imageUrl is not getting saved for some users and that is why app is crashing. I will try to figure that out, if you have any suggestion please help, Logcat posted. Please check. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try doing this

```
  mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

in

```
 mUsers = new ArrayList<>();
    db.collection("users")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                            Users users = document.toObject(Users.class);
                            mUsers.add(users);
                        }
//HERE
                        mAdapter = new UsersAdapter(MainActivity.this, mUsers);
                        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                        ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar9);
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Also make sure that your string with the url of the image isn't empty, in that case if some users haven't a imgurl just do a try catch in  onBindViewHolder our just check of the image is empty with an if

Comment: Yes I got the answer, the problem was related to no image url.